# Dynamically Generate Groupboxes

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on an inventory program and have finished the main functionality as a command line console app. I am now working on a version for winforms. I want to enable it to dynamically generate a Groupbox that holds some textboxes. I'd rather not design 50+ lines of multiple textboxes. Keep in mind I'm rather new to programming, having started with C# a year ago. I know next to nothing on Winforms.

I've tried to use `dynamic item = new Groupbox();`as a similar method allowed generation of objects at runtime. In the command line app, the way it works is that based on information given, a certain amount of objects are passed into the list _AllItems. I was thinking of generating the Groupboxes by using:

```
private void InitializeGroupBox()
        {
            foreach (Product product in Product._AllItems)
            {
                dynamic Item = new GroupBox();
            }

        }
```

But I have the feeling I'm nowhere near the correct method. Thanks to anybody who helps.

Comment: groupbox is a container type controller and usually other controls are embedded inside it. It is better to create a list and put the list in the groupbox

Comment: You might want to look at a the [DataGridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/datagridview-control-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) instead.  Alternatively, create one FlowLayoutPanel before the loop, then dynamically create TextBoxes within the loop and add them to the FlowLayoutPanel.

Comment: Well the start is correct but you also need to add the new controls to the parent control, most liekly the Form or a TabPage..: `dynamic Item = new GroupBox(); Item.Parent = thisOrSomeTabPage;`; It is also a great idea to add them Groupboxes to a Dictionary>string, GroupBox> with a nice name as the key, so you can refer to them later when you add the TextBoxes or whatever..

Comment: You are conflating dynamic generation with dynamic typing. You don't need to use dynamic typing. Take a look inside the .designer.cs code for your form to get an idea of how to add controls programmatically -- the patterns used in there that were generated by the designer can be written anywhere else in your program to add controls "on the fly".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to learn a bit more, but here is what I usually do to achieve what you asked.

```
internal class DynamicForm : Form
{
    private FlowLayoutPanel mFlowLayoutPanel;

    public DynamicForm() 
    {
        mFlowLayoutPanel = new FlowLayoutPanel();
        mFlowLayoutPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        // Add to this Form
        this.Controls.Add(mFlowLayoutPanel);

        InitializeGroupBox();
    }

    private void InitializeGroupBox()
    {
        mFlowLayoutPanel.SuspendLayout(); // Performance

        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
            var groupBox = new GroupBox();
            groupBox.Text = "GroupBox #" + i;
            groupBox.Size = new Size(200, 50);

            var textBox = new TextBox();
            textBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            // Add the TextBox to GroupBox
            groupBox.Controls.Add(textBox);

            // Add to this Form
            mFlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(groupBox);
        }

        mFlowLayoutPanel.ResumeLayout(); // after suspend, resume!
    }
}
```